# idea about a app in group theory

Tags: group-theory, programming

I have a idea about a app or software but because I don't know any programming language i don't know if it is doable
idea is simple for every group we can chose some properties for example being finite, abelian, 2-generator and ... then app search in its database and fine related well known theorems or lemmas or maybe some famous example if available.
its seems useful apps because this way we don't have to thinks or search for hours for some theorems or lemmas especially in field we are not completely familiar with.
I think couple of programmer's and colleague student is enough to do it.
do you think this is doable?

Comment: Do you mean like [this](https://nathancarter.github.io/group-explorer/index.html)?

Comment: although it is good at least about examples but not what i meant. we can give it properties and result will be well known theorems related to properties

Comment: I think this is an awesome idea and Shaun that website looks great I love that they have the Cayley diagrams too

Comment: @rschwieb has a website with the same thing but for rings : http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @Shaun : I don't know if it's your website, but if it is, may I suggest a (very slight) improvement ? It would be changing the word "definition" into "presentation"

Comment: I have thought about adapting [π-base](https://topology.jdabbs.com)(which is similar to what you are suggesting but it is for topological spaces) to basically do what you are looking for. It would be awesome if someone set it up(I probably won't).